# Where do you put Log::listen?

Tags: events, logging, laravel-5

I have a simple Laravel 5 application.

I don't know where to put the snippet

```
Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context)
{
    //
    doStuff();
});
```

I tried to put it in the routes.php but:

- first, `doStuff()` is never reached
- secondly, I'm not sure this is the right place as I also have Artisan commands and I don't think they use the routes file.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good place is to write new Middleware or do your own ServiceProvider. I find myself Middleware easier.

Read more from http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware